# I still have a 3K privilege notification in my Achievements list after dropping below 3K

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, privileges, achievements-dialog

A few days ago, I saw that my Achievements list contained a notification informing me that I'd earned the 3K reputation privilege ("cast close & reopen votes").

Then my reputation dropped below 3K, but I still saw the notification. I thought it would be removed after some time, but even 4 hours later it remained.

[image: 3K rep privilege notification shown on 2998-rep account]

Comment: I have no idea what you're saying. You need to make it a bit clearer what happened and what you expected to happen.

Comment: image it self says everything,,yet my question is without reaching 3k repo..it should not show in my notification about that previliege

Comment: yeah i understand that,but aint it bug? it must be fix